# uneven steering effort

Tags: power-steering, steering, cobalt

('07 Cobalt LS; rack & pinion, with electric power steering.)

Lately, I've felt there might be a hitch in the steering, occurring when straightening out after rounding a corner.  The effect is subtle, and possibly all in my head.

So, I put the front end up.  With engine off, key on, I can turn the steering wheel.  But, at about +/- 45-degrees rotation, the effort needed to turn abruptly substantially increases, and remains at the higher level beyond that point.  It isn't *hard* to turn; just, there's a noticeable change.  If it matters, there is negligible slop in the linkage.  The anti-theft steering lock occurs at ~90 degrees rotation.

Anyway, that's the question: is it normal for steering resistance to change like that?  Thanks.

Comment: Is there any noise you'd consider abnormal when doing this (engine off/key on)?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2: nope.  Quiet as a mouse.

Answer (score 1):

The u-joint coupling the (steering) intermediate shaft and the rack's pinion shaft is rusted up.